# What is the limit of series $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{nk}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How can I find the limit of series $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{nk}$?

I need to show that this series converges to $0$ as $n\to \infty$ in order to prove that the Cauchy Product of two non-absolutely convergent series can converge. I multiplied $\sum a_k=\sum \frac{(-1)^k}{k}$, where $a_0=0,$ by itself. And I got $b_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{n-k} \cdot a_k= \frac{2 \cdot (-1)^n}{n} \cdot \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k}$. My plan is proving that $\sum b_n$ is convergent by Leibniz Criterion. However I could not do anything in order to prove as $n \to \infty$ $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{nk} \to 0$ . I would be glad if someone point out what should I do.

EDIT: I guess I've proved without using any "too strong" theorem or tool.

Let us say $c_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{nk}= \frac{1}{n} \cdot [\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}+ \ldots +\frac{1}{n-1}]$.

Then there exist $l \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $2^{l}<n-1$, but $2^{l+1} \ge n-1$.

Thus, $c_n< \frac{1}{n} \cdot [\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+ \ldots +\frac{1}{2^l}+\frac{1}{2^l}+ \ldots+\frac{1}{2^l}]$, where there are $2^l$ many $\frac{1}{2^l}$ terms.

Hence, $c_n < \frac{1}{n} \cdot(l+1)$. Moreover since $2^l<n-1$, we have $l<\log_{2}{(n-1)}$.

Thus, $c_n<\frac{1}{n} \cdot(1+\log_{2}{(n-1)})$. If we consider $0<c_n$ for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and use the associated funciton of $\frac{(1+\log_{2}{(n-1)})}{n}$ we get; $0 \le c_n \le \frac{(1+\log_{2}{(x-1)})}{x}$. After that taking the limit as $x \to \infty$ we can easily see $c_n \to 0$, by using L'Hospital rule and squeeze theorem.

Comment: Take the $1/n$ outside the sum and use an estimate for partial sums of the harmonic series?

Comment: I thought that but isn't the divergence of the series $\sum \frac{1}{k}$ problematic? Since as $n\to \infty$ the series diverges.

Comment: Have you heard of Cesaro sums? a particular use of this is a a result that states that if $a_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow}a$, then $\frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{k=1}a_k\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}a$. There us also Stolz's theorem, but that is a little of an overkill for your situation.

Comment: I have not heard that but it looks nice. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Let $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1k$. By [Stolz's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem)($\cdot/\infty$ case),
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{S_n}n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{S_{n+1}-S_{n}}{(n+1)-n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n=0.$$

Comment: It looks so simple, thanks a lot!

Comment: @omnar Glad that helps!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{nk}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k}=\frac{H_{n-1}}{n}$$

Now, use the asymptotics
$$H_p=\gamma+\log(p)+\frac 1{2p}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^2}\right)$$ and continue with Taylor series.